java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ' com.intuit.karate.Main.parseKarateOptionsAndQuotePath(java.lang.String)'
I'm using karate 1.5.0.RC3 with Java 17.
When I'm trying to run a simple feature, I have the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.intuit.karate.Main com.intuit.karate.Main.parseKarateOptionsAndQuotePath(java.lang.String)'
What's the issue?
Thank you in advance
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>solvingError_Java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>solvingError_Java</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.karatelabs</groupId>
      <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0.RC3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
      <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.11.0-M2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.11.0-M2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
      <version>4.10.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js</artifactId>
      <version>21.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.graalvm.js</groupId>
      <artifactId>js-scriptengine</artifactId>
      <version>21.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>

I try to run this simple feature.
Feature: My first feature with Karate

  Background:

    * configure ssl = true
    * url 'https://myurl'


  Scenario: test de connexion 

    Given path 'my path'
    When method GET
    Then status 200

I'm expecting that the test run well

sorry that pom is a mix of all kinds of things and wrong versions. the first thing you should do is try a quickstart: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - only you are in a position to figure this out

Note that NoSuchMethodError is a common symptom of a version mismatch.

Am also facing the same issue inspite of using same version 1.5.0 in both karate-core and karate-junit dependencies with group id as io.karatelabs. Any solution to rectify this please

The method Main.parseKarateOptionsAndQuotePath() was removed in karate-core 1.5.0 as "dead code". It seems that it added some quotes to workaround some IDE issues before calling method Main.parseKarateOptions():

// adds double-quotes to last positional parameter (path) in case it contains white-spaces and un-quoted


// only if line contains just one positional parameter (path) and it is the last one in line.


// needed for intelli-j and vs-code generated cli invocations

You probably can just call Main.parseKarateOptions().
